# Can I share a stack between two toilets?

Tags: drain, drain-waste-vent, plumbing-fixture

I want to put another toilet/bathroom off my bedroom.  The main bathroom is next door to the cupboard I want to turn into my new bathroom.  What run do I need for the second toilet?  The main stack is in the main bathroom, so it would mean the new, second toilet would be 3' from the 1st toilet and about 5' for the main drainage stack.  Is it possible to run both toilets off the same run?

Comment: Possibly, depends on the existing configuration and sizes. New back to back bathrooms are constructed all the time so it is possible under the proper conditions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the plumbing code in your area. Where I live you'd need a permit to do something like this. Every fixture requires a minimum waste and vent pipe size, and adding more fixtures to a branch or stack could call for an increase in the diameter of those pipes. If you are determined to DIY you should at least refer to the local plumbing code to keep it legal. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

yes. Although I only have a few years of plumber assistance experience it sounds to me as if you have the perfect set up for your project.